# Connect Android device to host to update data

Tags: android, networking

I'm writing an Android application for Hotel Management. That each employee has own tablet running Android OS. this app sometimes will send data to host (that the room has been booked) or host will send data to client (about new condition of other rooms).

Host can be an another Android smartphone or a PC, and those device will connect together through same wifi network.

I don't know which way is easier (using smartphone for host or PC for host). If using PC, I decide that PC will have local server running database, and each tablet will connect to this server and update data from database. Does this easy to implement ?

Please help me figure out those problems. thanks :)

Comment: If my response was helpful, please mark as the answer and/or upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use PC/Server for the host so you can run a proper RDBMS.

There are tons of examples available for creating Android apps that talk to a variety of RDBMS systems. On your server you'll run an interpreter (PHP, ASP.NET, Node) and your Android app will connect to this over the Wifi network using http.

See example here:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/